# Not getting the expected response from Backend in web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an api call in AngularJS to get data from backend JAVA

Here is my code

```
$scope.memberForm = {}; 
$scope.memberForm.member_address = {}; 
$scope.memberRegForm = function() {
    $scope.btnloading = true;
    $('#add-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    url = '/member/add';
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data: angular.toJson($scope.memberForm),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    });
}
```

But I am not getting desire response from backed, Response that's I am actually getting from backend is

```
{
    "fullname":"sdfgsdf",
    "fathername":"sdfsdf",
    "email":"sdfsdf@gmail.com",
    "date_of_birth":"1993-03-24",
    "admission_date":"2018-10-22",
    "phoneno":"0987654321",
    "nationality":"United States",
    "member_address":
    {
        "address":"5 meadow st",
        "state":"Connecticut",
        "zipcode":"06770",
        "district":"zc"
    },
    "college":"cvbcv",
    "qualification":"bcvbcv",
    "slno_ivpr":"12"
}
```

But here is my desire response. I need `member_address` as an array of ojects instead of a single object

```
{
    "fullname": "avinash",
    "fathername": "xxxxxxx",
    "date_of_birth": "1991-08-08",
    "nationality": "indian",
    "admission_date": "2015-08-08",
    "college": "ABC college",
    "slno_ivpr": null,
    "phoneno": "1234567890",
    "email": "avinash.mitresource@gmail.com",
    "remarks": "no remarks",
    "member_renewal": [],
    "qualification": "MCA",
    "member_address": [
        {
            "address": "piratlanka,repalle",
            "state": "AP",
            "district": "Guntur",
            "zipcode": "522264",
            "type": "PermanentAddress"
        },
        {
            "address": "padamata",
            "state": "AP",
            "district": "vijayawada",
            "zipcode": "522201",
            "type": "ResidencialAddress"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should asked to Backend JAVA developer to provide you array of objects in `member_address` instead of object

Comment: If you are expecting `member_address` should be an array then you should have to assign it with an empty array E.g: `$scope.memberForm.member_address = {};` and change the key name to `member_addresses` *plural*